# modal dialogs with different close events

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid, modal-dialog

I'm subscribing to my bootstrap modal close event using

```
$(function () {
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        jQuery("#jqGrid2").jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: "/Types/GetTypes?sectionid=" + $('#Sections').val(), page: 1, $('#Sections').text }).trigger('reloadGrid');
    });
});
```

which works fine, it updates my jqgrid, Im using the same modal throughout my website but using different partials in it. now on one of my pages I need to update the grid if the user is adding a product to the grid and I use a modal to display a partial to them, but if they are adding a product type in the same modal but different partial I need to add that type to my dropdown list then update the dropdown list, is there a way I can attach a different id to the modal everytime i open it and use that id in the closed event? so I could say in my close event if id equals 1 update my grid, else if equals 2 update my dropdown with the new value the user typed into my partial form?

regards

Answer (score 0):

I went down the route of just adding a new modal with  a different id, added a new function to handle the close eventand some new javascript to open the modal and it works fine, I asked because I didn't want to get into the position of having lots of modals everywhere.